# Does anybody know of a tabbed FTP client?

Tags: tabs, ftp-client

Am I the only person who has the need to view multiple directories at once (usually on the same remote server, but sometimes other ones too)? Disconnecting and reconnecting is driving me crazy.

Preferably a free tool, but I'm getting to the stage where I'll try anything!

Can you have multiple FireFTP tabs in Firefox? Alternatively, I've thought of using [WinTabber](http://www.wintabber.com/) - I used it about 12 months ago for multiple PuTTY sessions, but it just felt a little clunky.

Cheers.

Comment: If disconnecting/reconnecting is driving you crazy, atleats open multiple instances of whatever ftp program you're currently using :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FireFTP** in Firefox does the job nicely. I've been using it about 2 hours and it's fast on the way to consigning FileZilla to the bin!

Answer (score 3):

[Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au/)

Answer (score 1):

[CrossFTP](http://www.crossftp.com/): Clients available for Windows, Mac OSX and Linux. Download is [here](http://www.crossftp.com/download.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I use [TotalCommander](http://www.ghisler.com/) as my default Windows file manager. It handles FTP as well and it is tabbed. It also handles tar files and a lot of other stuff that I really like. It's brilliant imo.

Answer (score -1):

[FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) 
is my favourite FTP client.

Comment: It's not tabbed though, is it?

Comment: It wasn't then, but is now (with version 3.3.5.1). So it retakes it's crown. IMHO.